# Shared contacts list

Tags: contacts

I want to have a shared contact list between two (or more) handsets. So that whenever someone is adding a contact to the list, it'll be automatically added to all handsets who share this.

It's very useful for people who work in the same place, and have many shared work-related contacts. Instead of making each employee add them to the contact list - any one who add work-related contact will add it to everyone.

How can I do that with Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is pretty easy.  There are two workable answers I can offer:

1. If you have Google Apps for your organization, you can simply turn
   on contact sharing and make sure everyone adds their Google Apps
   account to their phone.
2. If you don't have Google Apps or don't want to use contact sharing,
   simply set up a *single* dummy gmail/Google Apps account for *every*
   person to add to their phone.  Any contacts added to this account,
   be it via a phones or via the gmail contacts book, will appear
   on every phone whenever a sync happens.

**To add another account to your phone**:

```
Settings->Accounts and sync->Add account
```

After adding the account on the phone, make sure you click on it again and set syncing to just contacts and not gmail, calendar, etc (unless you want these)

Comment: Simple and beautiful. I knew about the Google Apps path, but I think about adding another account.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that, it's called [Shared Contact List](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.protieto.procontacts). It does exactly the thing you describe.

Disclaimer: I work at the company that made it.